# Android - Edittext vertical line in middle

Tags: android, android-edittext

I've a problem with a edittext, and I don't know how to resolve it.
The problem is that on middle of edittext there is a vertical line, how to remove it?
This problem is present only on smallscreen.

My code is:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/txt1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txt1"
        android:capitalize="none"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="text|textNoSuggestions"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="15dp" >
</EditText>
```

Thanks a lot

---

All code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layoutsolutionhorizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtquestionmethodhorizontal"
    android:gravity="top|center_vertical|center_horizontal" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtsolutionhorizontal0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:capitalize="none"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="text|textNoSuggestions"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="15dp" >
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtsolutionhorizontal1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtsolutionhorizontal0"
        android:capitalize="none"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="text|textNoSuggestions"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="15dp" >
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtsolutionhorizontal2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtsolutionhorizontal1"
        android:capitalize="none"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="text|textNoSuggestions"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="15dp" >
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtsolutionhorizontal3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtsolutionhorizontal2"
        android:capitalize="none"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="text|textNoSuggestions"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="15dp" >
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtsolutionhorizontal4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtsolutionhorizontal3"
        android:capitalize="none"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="text|textNoSuggestions"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="15dp" >
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtsolutionhorizontal5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtsolutionhorizontal4"
        android:capitalize="none"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="text|textNoSuggestions"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="15dp" >
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtsolutionhorizontal6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtsolutionhorizontal5"
        android:capitalize="none"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="text|textNoSuggestions"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="15dp" >
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtsolutionhorizontal7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtsolutionhorizontal6"
        android:capitalize="none"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="text|textNoSuggestions"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="15dp" >
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtsolutionhorizontal8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtsolutionhorizontal7"
        android:capitalize="none"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="text|textNoSuggestions"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="15dp" >
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtsolutionhorizontal9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtsolutionhorizontal8"
        android:capitalize="none"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="text|textNoSuggestions"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="15dp" >
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtsolutionhorizontal10"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtsolutionhorizontal9"
        android:capitalize="none"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="text|textNoSuggestions"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="15dp" >
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtsolutionhorizontal11"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtsolutionhorizontal10"
        android:capitalize="none"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="text|textNoSuggestions"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="15dp" >
    </EditText>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/buttonclearhorizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtsolutionhorizontal11"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/clearbox" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I call this layout in an other layout with command include

Screenshot is: [image]

Comment: If it's not the cursor, can you post a screenshot?

Comment: Remove the `+` in all the `layout_toRightOf=@+id/...` you have. The `+` is only used the first time to show that you're creating a new id.

Comment: sorry but it doens't work, but why I've this problem only with smallscreen?

Comment: Please share your testing device details, like Android version, device or emulator,resolution, screen size, etc.

Comment: I'm using android emulator with this characteristic:
Target: Android 2.3.3
Sd card: 100
Screen: QVGA
Density: 120
VM: 24
Ram: 256

Comment: Unable to reproduce the same issue. On the other hand would like to know why are you using RelativeLayout?  I am asking this because your relative layout properties are inappropriate. I would suggest using LinearLayout.

Comment: I've the same problem. Boh I don't know why there is the vertical line

Answer (score 7):

That's called the `cursor`. It's in the middle because you've set `gravity=center`. You can remove it using:

```
android:cursorVisible="false"
```

Comment: no it doens't work, this line is not a coursor but a vertical line.
The all xml is compose of 12 edittext and only 2 or 3 box has this problem (not all)

Comment: A screenshot would be better.

Comment: sorry but I'm new and cant't post the image

Comment: @user2226604 I think you can still link to the image hosted somewhere?

Comment: can u share the complete xml? seems systems ninepatch issue to me.